# Specify property types upon deserialization of Json to BsonDocument

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, bson

I'm trying to deserialize an unstructured JSON object (there are multiple schema possibilities) to a `BsonDocument`, and I'm trying to specify the correct types for some properties (which I know in advance).

Say for example (very simplified example):

```
{ "Id": "039665be-a1a8-4062-97d6-e44fea2affff", "Foo":"Bar", "Baz":30 }
```

So I know everytime I find an "Id" property (which may or may not be there) on the root of the object, this is to be converted to an UUID type (bson binary type 4).

I've made a simple `JsonReader` descendant, and I'm overriding `ReadBsonType`, and both returning a new `CurrentBsonType` and providing a converted value there, then overriding all methods for every possible type (`ReadDateTime()`, `ReadInt32()`, `ReadInt64()`, `ReadBinaryData()`, etc.) and providing a parsed value.

This works fine (albeit I find it a bit unconfortable) when the JSON object is plain, but if it has nested objects with properties of the same name (which I do not want to parse), then problems arise.

I've tried overriding `ReadStartArray()`, `ReadStartDocument()`, etc., and tried building a "path" which I can query to, but the actual order of the calling of the methods of the `JsonReader` are baffling to me (it seems to check for the type before checking for the name of the property, so the `CurrentName` property when checking for the type refers to the previous property, etc.).

I've somewhat circumvented it with **very ugly** code... and I'm sure there must be a better way to do this without class mapping, although finding documentation is proving hard (since mongo often calls "json" the actual "json extended", so documentation gets mixed from here and there).

Has anyone ever found themselves in such situation?

PS: before anyone asks, I'm storing data returned as json strings from a third party server on a mongo database (that will be mined later on), and while there are some schemas for the datatypes available (and I could classmap them), there might be new schemas in the future so I can't just classmap everything. Some properties (if they exist) are always the same though, so instead of storing everything on mongo as a string I'd rather give them the correct possible types from a start.